# Notify Adapter that Two Seperate Iems have Changed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Say I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` with 10 items. At some point in my code I update the data of *item 0* and *item 8*.

Is it safe to call `notifyItemChanged(0)` immediately followed by `notifyItemChanged(8)`?

Comment: try it ..........

Comment: Try to call notifyDataSetChanged method of adapter. It would automatically detect which data has been changed and corresponding views would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use notifyDataSetChanged(). But why shouldn't it be safe to call notifyItemChanged(i) twice?